# How to use window.localstorage saved data from a cross platform app to Android native app?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, local-storage

I have an app made witch has in **/data/data/com.pakage.name/app_webview/Local Storage/file__0.localstorage** data saved in a table. Is it a real .db file?  How can I use that table in android and query for some files, like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT value FROM ItemTable WHERE key='fav_list'";
```

I tried this:
**f.getPath** is the path to the file

`File dbfile = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(f.getPath());
dbfile.setWritable(true);
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbfile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can respond to my own answer after a little research.

> Is it a real .db file?

yes it is a database.

here it's how I managed to acces the row from column i wanted:

```
Cursor cursor = null;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
try {
     File dbfile = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(f.getPath());
     dbfile.setWritable(true);
     db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbfile.getAbsolutePath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

     String sql = "SELECT value FROM ItemTable WHERE key='fav_list'";
     cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
     cursor.moveToFirst();
      while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

            byte[] itemByteArray = cursor.getBlob(0);
            String itemString = new String(itemByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));
            cursor.moveToNext();
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
```

and with itemString you can do what you want. :)